# Applying variable to json path

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I'm creating a discord.js bot that needs to read some [json](http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.14.1/data/en_US/champion/Yasuo.json)
but I've stumbled upon a little problem. In my code I have a function that gets the champion name, then it applies it to the link ex. if user types !champion Yasuo it will search Yasuo.json. But when I'm requesting the JSON and reading it, I want to get a certain key, the lore of the champion. But the path looks like this ex. data.Yasuo.lore; Because in my code I have a variable that gets the champion name i want to apply it to the key path as well, but when I execute it it gives an error that the path couldn't be found because the path is res.data.championName.lore; such key doesn't exist.

What can I do with it? How can I apply a variable to the key path?

Code:

```
    function getChampion(championName){
         var url = `http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.14.1/data/en_US/champion/${championName}.json`
         request(url, (error, head, body)=>{
             var res = JSON.parse(body);
             var championDesc = res.data.championName.lore; //I want this to be for ex. res.data.Yasuo.lore; I want it as a variable.
             console.log(championDesc);
         })
    }
```

Comment: You have to use bracket notation when wanting to use variable, eg `data[championName]`

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to put the variable inside of brackets (`[]`) to correctly access the value within the JSON object. Here is an example of how that would work with the code you provided:

```
function getChampion(championName){
         var url = `http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.14.1/data/en_US/champion/${championName}.json`
         request(url, (error, head, body)=>{
             var res = JSON.parse(body);
             var championDesc = res.data[championName].lore; //I want this to be for ex. res.data.Yasuo.lore; I want it as a variable.
             console.log(championDesc);
         })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe i forgot such a basic thing, I guess that's what happens when you try to make something bigger than a console application haha.

Comment: No problem! Happens all the time